# The import android.* cannot be resolved for drag and drop example

Tags: android

I am new to java and android.I am following and making app from [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidDragAndDrop/article.html#dialog) for drag and drop.

the following files are giving error of cannot be resolved.

```
import android.view.View.DragShadowBuilder;
import android.view.View.OnDragListener;
import android.view.DragEvent;
import android.content.ClipData;
```

I know that means the above mentioned classes are not present in main library. how should i add them or is there alternate way of doing drag and drop(please explain with give examples).

Comment: They are defined in "Android 4.0 (Ice Cream Sandwich)" as it's written in article. You can write those methods by yourself, or you can set your target version to 4.0 and set your minSdkVersion to whatever you want in your manifest.xml

Comment: make sure you have Created Project for API Level 11 or greater then API Level 11

Comment: @Rajeshwaran.T I am using android 2.2 version....so what should I do....

Comment: @imrankhan     How could I make sure and check for which api level I have created a project....

Comment: you should change your project target 4.0.

Comment: @karan421 : Create your Project in android 3.0 or above from 3.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right click on your projects --> properties --> android ----> set target 4.0

Refer this links,

http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-beginner-tutorials/drag-and-drop-ui-element/

http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2010/04/simple-drag-n-drop-on-android.html

Comment: I think changing to target 4.0 it would work only with real hardwares having android 4.0 but I would like to develop for 2.2.....

Comment: @karan421 Drag and drop is api version 11 functionality (Android 3.0+). You can't use these classes and develop for Android 2.2 because these classes don't exist in that version.

Answer (score 1):

Try Right Click --> Android Tools --> Fix Project Properties, It worked for me.